# Multiple business unit configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud

If I want to use each country's local language on my email then do  I have to configure multiple business units or can it be achieved with a single BU?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through different email template depending on your requirement.

Comment: But won't creating multiple BU will be a one time effort. In that case singler email template can be used for all territories.

Comment: @GajendraSingh creating email template for one business unit than having separate Business Unit will save you from lot hassles in long run. Again it depends on what kind of requirement it is. You can do that by creating separate business unit of course.

Comment: Also, if i want to have the physical email address in localized language then i would surely need multiple BU's.  Is this understanding correct. Please help me on this as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Unless you are planning to roll out Marketing Cloud in the different countries, i.e. there will be dedicated people running their own campaigns etc, there's no need to go down the route of multiple BUs. The use cases that you mentioned, language version, different physical address can all easily achieved using Dynamic Content. As long as each subscriber receiving the E-Mail has an attribute indicating the country you can use this attribute for a simple If/Then rule using Dynamic Content.

Comment: Does this mean that to separately track information for campaign sent by each of the offices, I have to put them in separate BU's.
@ChristophCuquemel

Comment: Hi @gajendra, did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. You can either deploy different single sends from one single Business Unit using a dynamic template, i.e. you hit the send button multiple times for each corresponding target group, or you send one single, dynamic message to all recipients and look at the tracking for each country/region either using the Email Performance By Attribute Report (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_email_performance_by_attribute_report.htm) or if you have the right edition of Marketing Cloud you could use Discover for reporting.